# I need help running simple-scan 3.14.0

Tags: scanner

I have Simple-Scan 3.14.0 downloaded on a Lenovo running Ubuntu 14.04.  Simply put, I can't get it to run.  Where do I begin?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't get it to run how? What have you tried already? What errors are you getting. There is not enough information in your question to give a helpful answer so please add more info about the issue.

Comment: Sorry.  I am beginning to think that I should concentrate on MaxView instead of Simple-Scan.  I imagine that I can run the scanner with MaxView.  However, here is what I get when I try to install.....'Dependency is not satisfiable:libpoppler-qt 4-3(>=0.10)   Error

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the program in the Dash or the side bar or doesn't it start when you click it?

If you open up the terminal and type the following you will get to the man page of the program with information about the usage:

```
man simple-scan
```

(There's also a link for it: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/simple-scan.1.html. For more info about man type `man man` in the terminal.)

If this doesn't work, let us know and give us more detailed info about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I try to boot from the archive manager icon on the left.  I get something with various options other than scanning.  But let me back up.  I also downloaded MaxView, which I also can't get to run.  If I get MaxView to run, do I even need simple-scan?  Appreciate your feedback.   Hank

Comment: @user314056: Where did you download MaxView? I couldn't find it in the repositories, but I think found it as a download through Sourceforge. Is that correct? Also, does Ubuntu recognize the scanner. Check this Ubuntu page for [supported scanners](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Scanners).

Comment: Yes, I downloaded MaxView from:   http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxview/    The printer/fax/scanner/copier is a Brother-MFC-9420-CN.   Ubuntu recognizes the printer, but I can't bring the scanner online.  I appreciate your feedback.